# How do I get a UGA iTek ITUGA17D1 DisplayLink USB adaptor to work?

Tags: xorg, usb, displaylink

I really need to [run this product](http://www.itek.it:81/index.php/it/producttmp.html?page=shop.product_details&product_id=63&category_id=21&flypage=ilvm_fly_admirable.tpl) with a linux distro.
For first I choose Ubuntu but I do not have particular preference...
I need to run a 37" monitor in vertical way so with 1080x1920 resolution. 
Can you provide me a working solution? I tried a lot of forum solution but no one works.

I really need your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you don't connect the usb, then execute in terminal `lsusb` and update your post with this information ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the `xserver-xorg-video-displaylink` package to get this device working.  I am unsure whether it can handle 1920x1080, and suspect that the limited current state of XRandR support for this driver will make it difficult to use at 1080x1920.  That said, please try, and if it doesn't work, [file bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on launchpad: there's some chance that with sufficient debugging information, it can be made to work.

Note that you will need to manually configure an xorg.conf file to support this device: an example configuration (for a different displaylink device) is available in `/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video/displaylink/examples`